# Django AssertionError When Testing Edit Url

Tags: django, django-testing

I'm not able to test my django edit url. My list url test is working. I also tried in pytest-django with same result. Please help! (Update: added view.py code below).

```
urls.py
path('<pk>/edit/', MyModelUpdateView.as_view(), name='mymodel_edit')


tests.py

from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.login_email = 'email@email.com'
        self.login_password = 'password'
        self.client.login(email=self.login_email, password=self.login_password)
        self.myobject = MyModel.objects.create(
            name = 'test'
        )

    def test_mymodel_edit(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('mymodel_edit',kwargs={'pk': self.myobject.id}), follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    AssertionError: 404 != 200

    #alternate
    def test_mymodel_edit(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('mymodel_edit',kwargs={'pk': self.myobject.id}))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    AssertionError: 302 != 200

view.py
class MyModelUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ('name',)
    template_name = 'mymodel_edit.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('mymodel_list')
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the view? Can you inspect `response.redirect_chain` to see where you are getting redirected?

Comment: Thanks Iain. I updated the post to include the view. I also rant the response.redirect_chain, which yielded this: '[('/accounts/login/?next=/finmod/1/edit/', 302)]'

Comment: Looks like you have some kind of permission checking on the view that the user you are using is failing

Comment: Thanks, Iain. There was a login decorator on the view...once removed the test passed. Thanks again!